# Getting the exception Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy

Tags: android, twitter

i m doing twitter plugin in my  android application. In this while i run the twitter API separately its working perfectly, but after integrated into my app while i m 1st time login into twitter its shows the following exception :

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException: Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy.
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:206)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveAccessToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:108)
at com.dotinfotech.snapthat.twitter.TwitterApp$3.run(TwitterApp.java:242)
```

and i m getting the error form following line:

```
mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer,verifier);
```

plz any one help me...

Comment: Faced the same problem with Tumblr.